# react-native TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'o[d]') in packager/react-packager/src/Resolver/polyfills/console.js

Tags: react-native

A user is experiencing this problem on my iOS app built using react-native on an iPhone 6s Plus. I am not experiencing this problem on my personal iPhone 5s. Basically, after the app is started, the app is aborted after 3-4 seconds. I get the following stack trace on Sentry

[image: Call Stack on Sentry]

Here is the [link](https://sentry.io/share/issue/39383231312e313838363730343233/) to the call stack on Sentry

I was able to collect the crash log from the user as well. I have pasted the crash log in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/varungupta85/07efb0e8e6a29e14c0482b2116ed5800). Here is an excerpt from the crash log for the thread that crashed.

```
Thread 4 name:  Dispatch queue: com.facebook.react.ExceptionsManagerQueue
Thread 4 Crashed:
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib        0x000000019151a014 0x1914fb000 + 126996
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib      0x00000001915e1460 0x1915dc000 + 21600
2  libsystem_c.dylib            0x000000019148e3f4 0x19142b000 + 406516
3  libc++abi.dylib              0x0000000190f592d4 0x190f58000 + 4820
4  libc++abi.dylib              0x0000000190f76cc0 0x190f58000 + 126144
5  libobjc.A.dylib              0x0000000190f84844 0x190f7c000 + 34884
6  libc++abi.dylib              0x0000000190f7366c 0x190f58000 + 112236
7  libc++abi.dylib              0x0000000190f72f84 0x190f58000 + 110468
8  libobjc.A.dylib              0x0000000190f84690 0x190f7c000 + 34448
9  GalarmApp                    0x00000001001034a4 0x100038000 + 832676
10  GalarmApp                    0x0000000100102cd4 0x100038000 + 830676
11  libdispatch.dylib            0x00000001913d5200 0x1913d4000 + 4608
12  libdispatch.dylib            0x00000001913d51c0 0x1913d4000 + 4544
13  libdispatch.dylib            0x00000001913e3444 0x1913d4000 + 62532
14  libdispatch.dylib            0x00000001913d89a8 0x1913d4000 + 18856
15  libdispatch.dylib            0x00000001913e3940 0x1913d4000 + 63808
16  libdispatch.dylib            0x00000001913e538c 0x1913d4000 + 70540
17  libdispatch.dylib            0x00000001913e50ec 0x1913d4000 + 69868
18  libsystem_pthread.dylib      0x00000001915dd2c8 0x1915dc000 + 4808
19  libsystem_pthread.dylib      0x00000001915dcdb4 0x1915dc000 + 3508
```

I am not sure how to debug this problem. The sentry call stack suggests that it is a problem in the console polyfill in react-native. I don't have any console log statements in production mode but there may be some console log statements in the third party packages that I am using. The crash log from the phone is pretty cryptic itself not giving a lot of information.

Any kind of help in figuring out this problem is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: For me, the problem was wrong sourcemaps on Sentry which pointed to the wrong code.